# Setting up Google Analytics Goal for Facebook Messenger Plugin

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, event-tracking, plugin, chat

How do insert the plugin code to create an event to fire in Google Analytics whenever someone uses our Facebook chat plugin that is on our website? [image]

Comment: Your screenshot is from creating a "goal" based on events.  You can't create events on that form.

Comment: Well that makes sense. My question should have been how to turn a click to a button that runs a script into an event. If my script is the attached screenshot would I use something like this within that script to create an event? <button onclick="ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);">Example Button Text</button>

Comment: I removed some characters because it was too long. <!-- Load for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({xfbm: true,
    version : 'v3.3'
    }); };
  (function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.cc.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'fb-jssdk'));</script>
<!-- Your cc code -->
<div class="fb-cc"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="">
</div>

Comment: in the end, did it work?